# Implicit conversion and explicit conversion in c

Tags: c, programming-languages

Doing explicit conversion leads to implicit conversions of operands in an expression in c?

Ex :

```
 int x =10, y=20;
 float C =( float) x/y;
```

Here `x` is explicitly converted to `float`. does this conversion leads to implicit conversion of `y`?

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case it does.

After the cast, you have an `int` and a `float` as operands of the `/` operator.  At that point the **usual arithmetic conversions** apply and the value of `y` is converted to type float so both operands have a common type.

There would not be an implicit conversion if for example the type of `y` was float as both operands of `/` would have the same type.

Comment: What is the case it doesn't affect other operands

Comment: There also would be no implicit conversion of `y` if its type were `double`, even though that's not the same as `float`.  Instead, the result of the explicit conversion of `x` would be subject to a subsequent implicit conversion to `double`.